# Написать sql запрос для сравнения таблиц

Tags: mysql

У меня есть две таблицы в бд posts, в ней строки

[image: таблица my sql]

Как можно написать запрос если мне нужно вернуть название страны с бд по необходимому мероприятию,
например мне нужно узнать в какой странне происходит wedding...

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял вопрос

```
SELECT p.id, c.country_name
FROM posts p
LEFT join countries c ON p.country = c.id
WHERE p.title LIKE "wedding";
```

Comment: что обозначает posts p и p.country и p.tittle?

Comment: @Daniil  `posts p` => `posts AS p` - краткое наименование, очевидно.

Comment: `select distinct` тут вообще не помешает. и `like` заменить на обычное равенство. да left join на inner join можно.

Comment: Если не трудно ,мне немного по другому нужно ... должно на фронт возвращать все поля с таблицы пост по id ,но country(int) заменять на country_name(text) по id с таблицы countries

Comment: @teran `LIKE` я обычно использую для того, чтобы не беспокоиться о больших или маленьких буквах в сравнении, он сработает и на `Wedding` и на `wEDDiing`, просто перестраховка

Comment: @Daniil я обновил запрос, возвращает `post.id` и `countries.country_name`

Comment: @zippp *`LIKE` я обычно использую для того, чтобы не беспокоиться о больших или маленьких буквах в сравнении* Вот две в принципе не связанные вещи. Регистрозависимость определяет COLLATION, и она одинакова для любого оператора сравнения - хоть обычное сравнение, хоть LIKE, хоть REGEXP.

Comment: @Akina спасибо, знаю, что есть настройки на эту тему, но чисто из практики сейчас прямо проверил следующее:
`select firstName from User where firstName = "ivan";` (0 записей)
`select firstName from User where firstName LIKE "ivan";` (3 записи)
Примерно поэтому предпочитаю в таких случаях использовать `LIKE` т.к. доступа к настройке мускуля у меня нет

Comment: @zippp Более чем странно выполнять сравнение выражений, не обеспечив необходимых условий их эквивалентности. *доступа к настройке мускуля у меня нет* А нафиг он нужен, доступ к настройкам? тут речь идёт даже не о настройках сессии (к которым гарантированно есть доступ) - достаточно просто явно указать collation в запросах.

Comment: @Akina прям проснулась ностальгия по менторскому тону русскоязычного сегмента :) 
подскажите пример пожалуйста, действительно интересно как это делается правильно. Большим плюсом было бы еще и использование Doctrine. Спасибо

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2bcb1f2853e31bf62b0e019368ad77bd